# Factor out a symbolic equation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is there an algorithm to factor out a symbolic equation, for example such as:

ab + ac + b^2 + bc

into:

(a+b)(c+b)

if there is, is it possible to extend this algorithm to more complicated equations so that the end result might be something like:

(e + f + ...)*( g + h + ..)*()*...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you want to solve is the factorisation of multivariate polynomials. There are algorithms for this, but they are probably not easy to understand or implement without having a background in abstract algebra. The following couple of links may be useful:

1. [Factorization of polynomials (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials)
2. [abstract algebra - Algorithms for factoring multivariate polynomials (math.SE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703962/algorithms-for-factoring-multivariate-polynomials)